# How to return the value which has the highest number of duplicates in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array and I want to find out which value exist multiple times more than any other number in the array. Can you please help me to solve it?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 2 
    [2] => 2 
    [3] => 1 
    [4] => 2 
    [5] => 2
)
```

The output I want is `2` as it has duplicated 4 times.

Answer (score 4):

You can use array_count_values for the same.

```
// fetched number of occurences of values
$temp = array_count_values($arr); 
// array_search max value in array and show key of it
echo array_search(max($temp), $temp);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EVcGr).

**Output**: 2

Answer (score 1):

Use array_count_values() function to count all the values of an array.

and to get the key of the maximum value of the array we have to use array_keys function.

```
<?php
    $a=array("1","2","1","4","1");
        $ar= array_count_values($a);
        $b= array_keys($ar,max($ar));
        echo $b[0];

?>
```